# showing multiple content on clicking through radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this to show multiple contents when you click through radio buttons. And I cant see the content. But when I am changing ti value to 1,2 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 it works fine. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

```
var options = $('#options').find('input');

    options.click(function(){
    $('#deafaultBottom').hide();
      var id = "opt" + $(this).val();
      $(".optDivs").hide();
      $("#" + id).show();

    });
```

and this is my html structure

```
<div id="options">
        <div class="opt1"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="color" /></div>
        <div class="opt2"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="dry" /></div>
        <div class="opt3"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="damaged" /></div>
        <div class="opt4"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="thinning" /></div>
    </div>

<div class="holderOne">
        <div id="opt1" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom1.png" /></div>
        <div id="opt2" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom2.png" /></div>
        <div id="opt3" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom3.png" /></div>
        <div id="opt4" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom4.png" /></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the values are 'color', 'dry', 'damaged' ad 'thinning' but your holder id's are opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4. What you want to do is put '1', '2', '3' and '4' in your options and put some text next to them for what you want the user to see. Here is your code with the suggested modifications:

```
<div id="options">
    <div class="opt1"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="1" />color</div>
    <div class="opt2"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="2" />dry</div>
    <div class="opt3"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="3" />damaged</div>
    <div class="opt4"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="4" />thinning</div>
</div>

<div class="holderOne">
    <div id="opt1" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom1.png" /></div>
    <div id="opt2" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom2.png" /></div>
    <div id="opt3" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom3.png" /></div>
    <div id="opt4" class="optDivs" style="display:none;"><img src="images/bigBottom4.png" /></div>
</div>
```

and [here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weDj4/) with the code working and some text added to the divs (1,2,3,4) to show that it is switching correctly.

Comment: @Benjamin-the problem is i am sending the value as an email. So when the customers get the 1,2,3,4 in their email they would get confused.

Comment: Where is the code for the email you are sending? Is it in PHP? Just create an associative array on the server side that decodes it back (I can help with the code if you show me what your email sending looks like).

Another option is to name your holderOne div id's to be 'optColor', 'optDry', 'optDamaged', 'optThinning' and make your values be 'Color', 'Dry', 'Damaged' and 'Thinning' respectively. See [this forked JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FY4E9/1/)

Comment: @benjamin-I like your second option. I think I might end up posting the data into a database so I will not spend too much time in modifying the PHP..but you just solved my problem with your second fiddle. Thanks man

Comment: @soum could you please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you. And no problem man :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var options = $('#options').find('input');
    options.click(function(){
      $('#deafaultBottom').hide();
      $(".optDivs").hide();
      $("#" + $($(this).parent()).attr('class') ).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var options = $('#options').find('input');

options.click(function () {
    // I have no idea what element you're affecting here
    $('#deafaultBottom').hide();
    // using the class-name of the parent div element
    var ref = this.parentNode.className;
    // hiding all divs within the .holderOne element
    $('.holderOne div').hide();
    // showing the element that has the same id as the
    // parent's class-name
    $('#' + ref).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NF6yv/).

This takes advantage of the fact that the element to *show* has an `id` attribute to match the class-name of the `radio`'s parent `div` element.

As the parent `div` element may have multiple classes, you could use a regex to identify the class-name that begins with the string `opt` and is followed by a number:

```
var options = $('#options').find('input');

options.click(function () {
    $('#deafaultBottom').hide();
    var ref = this
    .parentNode
    // matches the first instance in which the string 'opt' is followed by
    // a, or a sequence of, number(s).
    .className.match(/\b(opt\d+)\b/)[0];
    console.log(ref);
    $('.holderOne div').hide();
    $('#' + ref).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NF6yv/1/).